# Find a tight upper bound of the following expectation.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sequences-and-series, inequality, convex-analysis

I am stuck in finding a tight upper bound (as tight as possible) of the following expectation $$E\left [ (1-a\cdot b^{X})^{m} \right ]$$ where $X\sim B(n-1,p)$ is a binomial random variable.In addition, $a\in (0,1]$,$b\in (0,1]$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ are all constants.
By the way ,I have found the following upper bound according to the Edmundson-Madansky Inequality.$$E\left [ (1-a\cdot b^{X})^{m} \right ]\leq \frac{(1-a\cdot b^{n-1})^{m}-(1-a)^{m}}{1- b^{n-1}}(1-E\left [ b^{X} \right ])+(1-a)^{m}$$
But it's not tight,especially for large $n$ and $m$.Can anyone find a tighter upper bound? Good approximation of this expectation is also appreciated.